# How can I clean this up with piping or not running a for loop through dataframe?

Tags: r, excel

I currently execute this code to scrub some excel files. I wanted to know what piping could look like to clean this up and maybe even achieving the same thing through a list using the purrr and map functions. This code basically

1. Reads in excel files
2. Removes unwanted special characters
3. Writes out to specified folders based on some conditions

Thank you.

```
files <- 
  list.files(path = "folder1/", pattern = "*xls")

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  files1 <- 
    basename(files[i]) 
  
  files1 <- gsub(pattern = "'", replacement = "" , x = files1) 
  files1 <- gsub(pattern = "\\*", replacement = "" , x = files1)
  
  data <- 
    read_excel(paste0("folder1/", files[i])) 
  
  data$column1 <- as.character(data$column1) 
  data <- data %>% 
    mutate(charCount = nchar(data$column1))
  data <- data %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), str_trim))
  
  if(any(grepl(pattern = "10", x = data$charCount) == FALSE) || any(grepl(pattern = "Coolguy",x = data$column5,ignore.case = T) == TRUE)) {
    write_xlsx(data, path = (paste0("bad/", files1, "x")))
  }
  if (any(grepl(pattern = "10", x = data$charCount) == TRUE) && any(grepl(pattern = "Coolerguy",x = data$column4,ignore.case = T) == TRUE)){
    write_xlsx(data[,1:11], path = (paste0("good/", files1, "x"))) 
  }else{
    write_xlsx(data[,1:11], path = (paste0("bad/", files1, "x")))
  }}
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a better question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Piping aside, I see multiple (syntax) issues with the code in its current form: (1) Don't use `$`-indexing inside `mutate`. (2) Don't use regexp to check for (integer) value conditions. (3) Don't use hard-coded folder names. (4) The return value of `any` is a logical scalar, so `if (any(...) == TRUE)` is redundant and should be `if (any(...))`. (5) Instead of `||` you need `|`(take a look at `help('|')` to understand the difference).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you could do it:

**Step 1**: Define the file names

```
file_names = list.files(path = "folder1/", pattern = "*xls") %>%
  map(basename) %>%
  map(~ gsub(pattern = "'|\\*", replacement = "", x = .x))
```

Note how I combined the two `gsub()` calls you originally had into one.

**Step 2**: Create a function for cleaning the data and apply this function on each file.

```
clean_data = function(data) {
  data %>%
    mutate(
      column1 = as.character(column1)
    ) %>%
    mutate(
      charCount = nchar(column1),
      across(where(is.character), str_trim)
    )
}

all_data = file_names %>%
  map(~ read_excel(file.path("folder1", .x))) %>%
  map(clean_data)
```

Note how we use `file.path()` instead of `paste0()` for specifying the file path in `read_excel()`. We will also use `file.path()` in Step 3. (See @Martin Gal's comment)

**Step 3**: Create a function for saving the data and apply this function on each dataset using `walk()`.

```
save_data = function(data, file_name) {
  charcount_10 = data$charCount == 10
  coolguy = grepl(pattern = "Coolguy", x = data$column5, ignore.case = TRUE)
  coolerguy = grepl(pattern = "Coolerguy", x = data$column4, ignore.case = TRUE)
  
  if (any(!charcount_10) || any(coolguy)) {
    write_xlsx(data, path = file.path("bad", file_name, "x"))
  } 
  if (any(charcount_10) && any(coolerguy)){
    write_xlsx(data[, 1:11], path = file.path("good", file_name, "x"))) 
  } else {
    write_xlsx(data[,1:11], path = file.path("bad", file_name, "x"))
  }
}
walk2(all_data, file_names, save_data)
```

Step 3 notes:

- I updated the `charCount == 10` condition as per @Maurits Evers's helpful note (you should not be using `grepl()` on numeric vectors, and `data$charCount` is a numeric vector.
- Did you mean the second `if()` statement to actually be an `else if ()` statement?
- I use `walk2()` to iterate over each dataset and its corresponding file name.

Comment: For creating path names, you could use `file.path`, which is _designed to be fast (faster than paste) as this function is used extensively in R itself._ (source: `?file.path`). This also saves you from using `/` and focuses on the folder names only.

Comment: Good point, thanks Martin. I've updated the paths in the code to use `file.path()`

Comment: Thanks a ton for the review - I'm learning quite a bit it seems! Can I ask? - what is the difference between using `charCount == 10` and say nchar(x) == 10? Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that it's helpful. There's no actual difference: `data$charCount == 10` and `nchar(data$column1) == 10` are the same. I only used the former because I followed your code, and in your code you defined a column in `data` called `charCount`.